# Click or tap won't register on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, svg, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on this SVG mobile touch indicator in jQuery Mobile 1.3.1:

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/MCt5X/1/embedded/result/

But why am I not getting the confirmation message after clicking the button whilst emulating the iPhone 5 in Chrome dev tools?

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    $('button').on('vmouseup', function (event) {
        showTouchIndicator(event);
    });

    function showTouchIndicator(event) {
        var touchIndicator = $("#touchIndicatorDiv");
        var touchIndicatorTemplate = $("#touchIndicatorTemplate");

        touchIndicator.html(touchIndicatorTemplate.html());

        touchIndicator.css('left', event.pageX - 30);
        touchIndicator.css('top', event.pageY - 30);

        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you replace vmouseup with vclick, it is a jQuery Mobile event meant to bridge click /tap differences, basically it will work in any environment

```
$('.ui-page').on('vclick', 'a, button, input[type="submit"]',function(event) {
    showTouchIndicator(event);
});:
```

Comment: I can get it to work on desktop and mobile (Chrome emulation) with `click`. With `vclick` it only works on desktop: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/LnhrF/9/ -- any ideas?